# How to migratef from log4j to log4j2 and editing the log4j properties file in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j, log4j2

Hi in my Spring boot application POM file I have added below dependancy for log4j2.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and how can I change the log4j.properties file according to that.

currently my log4j.properties is as below.

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN,ConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.layout=net.logstash.log4j.JSONEventLayoutV1

log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern={"AAA": "TEST-SERVICE","correlation-id" : "%X{id}", timestamp":"%d{sdwqd}", "thread": "%t",  "logging event": "%p", "class": "%c", "method": :"%M", "line":"%L", "message": "%m"}%n
```

And can I still use the ConsoleAppender even using log4j2 ? . Any response really appreciate.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using log4j2, I used logback-spring.xml and used its dependancy and it works. 
This migration really need when we are migrating from spring boot version 1.x to 2.x
Thanks.